# If every element on the page is sized in percentages, would zooming the browser window do anything?

Tags: html, css

If there was no font, and nothing but block level elements, and the zoom on a page was adjusted, will anything change?

It seems that, because everything would be based on it's parents width / height (and none of those change when the browser is zoomed) then nothing would change. Is this right?

Comment: Before you asked your question, did you try it to see what would happen? What were your results? In what browsers? Are you asking about what happens (observation) or what *should* happen (the specification)?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. However, font-size needs to be in `vw` because percentages won't work.

```css
head {
  display: none;
}
* {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #130f0e;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 2% 0 0 1%;
  padding: 3%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 3vw;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Header Text</h3>
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```